# pick up 2 rows from csv and convert to xml

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, csv

My text file has 100's of entries like below.. I want my code to catch each event which has 14 or 15 elements seperated by delimiter ( | ) and put them in xml. Each event should be captured in new  tag.

6354|,EGZ|2023012711283700|900|DDIC|S000|R_JR_BTCJOBS_GENERATOR||1|25737,00088,B5|SAP_WORKFLOW_WIM_ACTION/11283700&JOB_CLOSE&&&&|43AE5E5C16990580E0063BBEAE21BEA8|42010A2A25FA1EDDA7CN
BDA81EE66224C|0000000000000000000000000000000000000\000000000000000000
6355|,EGZ|2023012711283700|900|DDIC|S000|R_JR_BTCJOBS_GENERATOR||1|25737,00088,B5|SAP_WORKFLOW_WIM_ACTION/11283700&JOB_CLOSE&&&&|43AE5E5C16990580E0063BBEAE21BEA8|42010A2A25FA1EDDA7CN
BDA81EE66224C|0000000000000000000000000000000000000\000000000000000000s

```
Expected output is this:
</Processes>
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <name>
   <Time>6354</Time>
   <Client>,EGZ</Client>
   <User>2023012711283700</User>
   <number>900</number>
   <processid>DDIC</processid>
   <program>S000</program>
   <randomnumber>R_JR_BTCJOBS_GENERATOR</randomnumber>
   <processidandwp></processidandwp>
   <userclient>1</userclient>
   <transactionid>25737,00088,B5</transactionid>
   <additional1>text</additional1>
   <additional2>43AE5E5C16990580E0063BBEAE21BEA8</additional2>
   <additional3>42010A2A25FA1EDDA7CN</additional3>
   <additional4>BDA81EE66224C</additional4>
   <additional5>000000000000000000/00000000000</additional5>
  </name>
  <name>
   <Time>6355</Time>
   <Client>,EGZ</Client>
   <User>2023012711283700</User>
   <number>900</number>
   <processid>DDIC</processid>
   <program>S000</program>
   <randomnumber>R_JR_BTCJOBS_GENERATOR</randomnumber>
   <processidandwp></processidandwp>
   <userclient>1</userclient>
   <transactionid>25737,00088,B5</transactionid>
   <additional2>43AE5E5C16990580E0063BBEAE21BEA8</additional2>
   <additional3>42010A2A25FA1EDDA7CN</additional3>
   <additional4>BDA81EE66224C</additional4>
   <additional5>000000000000000000/00000000000</additional5>
  </name>
 </Processes>

The current output that I get is this
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
 <Processes>
  <name>
  <Time>6354</Time>
  <Client>,EGZ</Client>
  <User>2023012711283700</User>
  <number>900</number>
  <processid>DDIC</processid>
  <program>S000</program>
  <randomnumber>R_JR_BTCJOBS_GENERATOR</randomnumber>
  <processidandwp></processidandwp>
  <userclient>1</userclient>
  <transactionid>25737,00088,B5</transactionid>
  <additional1>SAP_WORKFLOW_WIM_ACTION/</additional1>
  <additional2>43AE5E5C16990580E0063BBEAE21BEA8</additional2>
  <additional3>42010A2A25FA1EDDA7CN</additional3>
 </name>
 <name>
  <Time>BDA81EE66224C</Time>
  <Client>0000000000000000000000000000000000000\000000000000000000</Client>
 </name>
 <name>
  <Time>6355</Time>
  <Client>,EGZ</Client>
  <User>2023012711283700</User>
  <number>900</number>
  <processid>DDIC</processid>
  <program>S000</program>
  <randomnumber>R_JR_BTCJOBS_GENERATOR</randomnumber>
  <processidandwp></processidandwp>
  <userclient>1</userclient>
  <transactionid>25737,00088,B5</transactionid>
  <additional1>SAP_WORKFLOW_WIM_ACTION/11</additional1>
  <additional2>43AE5E5C16990580E0063BBEAE21BEA8</additional2>
  <additional3>42010A2A25FA1EDDA7CN</additional3>
 </name>
 <name>
  <Time>BDA81EE66224C</Time>
  <Client>0000000000000000000000000000000000000\000000000000000000s</Client>
 </name>
</Processes>

My code which i got is this:
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

row_names = [
 'Time',
 'Client',
 'User',
 'number',
 'processid',
 'program',
 'randomnumber',
 'processidandwp',
 'userclient',
 'transactionid',
 'additional1',
 'additional2',
 'additional3',
 'additional4'
]
root = ET.Element("Processes")
counter = 0
with open("data.csv", 'r') as file:
 csv_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter="|")
 sub_root = ET.SubElement(root, 'name')
 for row in csv_reader:
    for name in row:
        if counter < len(row_names) and name:
            ele = ET.SubElement(sub_root, row_names[counter])
            ele.text = name
            counter += 1

ET.dump(root)
```

If you see my current output vs expected output, I want to have the expected output. For now...when the code reads the rows from the file, as soon as it reaches the 2nd row ( for the 1st event) or 4th row ( for the 2nd event) , it creates a new  tag. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes if you see my current output vs expected output, I want to have the expected output. For now...when the code reads the rows from the file, as soon as it reaches the 2nd row ( for the 1st event) or 4th row ( for the 2nd event) , it creates a new <name> tag.  Does it make sense?

Comment: can't you see you're missing the "|" after 42010A2A25FA1EDDA7CN?

Comment: Thats the thing, there is no | ..its a single word just on the next line..the code should be able to capture that

Comment: Your desired output contains an XML node `<additional5>` but your python `row_names` list does not contain an `additional5` item.   Further, your if check `if counter < len(row_names) and name:` will preclude any empty tags in your output XML.

Comment: Can you manipulate the data.csv file prior to executing your python code?

Comment: Your XML declaration in your desired output should be the first line in the XML not the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming an even number of lines in `data.csv`.  The following refactored python code may work for you.  Combine every 2 lines into a single pipe-delimited record that is split into an array. For each item in the array build an XML node using the corresponding node name from the `row_names` array.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import itertools

node_names = ['Time','Client','User','number','processid',
'program','randomnumber','processidandwp','userclient','transactionid',
'additional1','additional2','additional3','additional4','additional5']

root = ET.Element('Processes')
with open('data.csv') as f:
    for l1,l2 in itertools.zip_longest(*[f]*2):
        sub_root = ET.SubElement(root, 'name')
        for idx, item in enumerate("".join([l1.strip(), l2.strip()]).split("|")):
            ele = ET.SubElement(sub_root, node_names[idx])
            ele.text = item

ET.indent(root, space="  ", level=0)
ET.dump(root)
```

Output:

```
<Processes>
  <name>
    <Time>6354</Time>
    <Client>,EGZ</Client>
    <User>2023012711283700</User>
    <number>900</number>
    <processid>DDIC</processid>
    <program>S000</program>
    <randomnumber>R_JR_BTCJOBS_GENERATOR</randomnumber>
    <processidandwp />
    <userclient>1</userclient>
    <transactionid>25737,00088,B5</transactionid>
    <additional1>SAP_WORKFLOW_WIM_ACTION/11283700&amp;JOB_CLOSE&amp;&amp;&amp;&amp;</additional1>
    <additional2>43AE5E5C16990580E0063BBEAE21BEA8</additional2>
    <additional3>42010A2A25FA1EDDA7CNBDA81EE66224C</additional3>
    <additional4>0000000000000000000000000000000000000\000000000000000000</additional4>
  </name>
  <name>
    <Time>6355</Time>
    <Client>,EGZ</Client>
    <User>2023012711283700</User>
    <number>900</number>
    <processid>DDIC</processid>
    <program>S000</program>
    <randomnumber>R_JR_BTCJOBS_GENERATOR</randomnumber>
    <processidandwp />
    <userclient>1</userclient>
    <transactionid>25737,00088,B5</transactionid>
    <additional1>SAP_WORKFLOW_WIM_ACTION/11283700&amp;JOB_CLOSE&amp;&amp;&amp;&amp;</additional1>
    <additional2>43AE5E5C16990580E0063BBEAE21BEA8</additional2>
    <additional3>42010A2A25FA1EDDA7CNBDA81EE66224C</additional3>
    <additional4>0000000000000000000000000000000000000\000000000000000000s</additional4>
  </name>
</Processes>
```

Verification that source `data.csv` has 4 lines:

```
wc -l data.csv 
       4 data.csv
```

Comment: awk is not required. you can use the second delimiter with a second loop to split the column.. `for col in row: for name in col.split(" "): `

Comment: I think this still doesnt work for me as my events are spread across 2 rows and not one. Do you know how to factor in 2 rows . On my VM, the events are spread out in 2 rows...they are not correctly aligned in one row.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Per OP's clarification this will not suffice.

Comment: can you please share the awk command you had shared earlier..not able to see. That actually helped me a lot.

Comment: I will see if I can dig it up, but in this scenario it is unnecessary.  Please see the updated python code in my answer for a python-only solution.

Comment: For some reason, the awk code works perfect for me, thats why I wanted that as well.

Comment: Per OP's request, here is an awk command for munging the raw input data file to deal with the missing '|' and extra newline per event:  `awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="|"}{gsub(" ", OFS, $(NF-1))}1' orig.csv`

Comment: the revised code you sent kind of actually splits additional3 tag into 2 parts (additional3 and additional4) which should not be the case. It should take 42010A2A25FA1EDDA7CNBDA81EE66224C in one tag which is additional3

Comment: Ok, that should be a very simple fix in the revised code.  It should be a matter of changing the `|".join` to `"".join`

Comment: My confusion stems from the expected output you posted in your question. In that expected output XML, here are the contents of the 'additional3' and 'additional4' tags:  `<additional3>42010A2A25FA1EDDA7CN</additional3>
   <additional4>BDA81EE66224C</additional4>`

Comment: oh My bad, what is posted for additional 3 and 4 is wrong. I need the each value seperated by  | in 1 tag..so the whole word 42010A2A25FA1EDDA7CNBDA81EE66224C should be in one tag. Sorry for the confusion